# True blueblood made disturbance twice (6, 7)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

I found this note the other day...

> Captured confidante without *it* returning (6)
>   *Ca*pricious co*m*mitt*e*e accommodatio*n* aft*e*r r*a*ts *re*tu*r*n (4, 7)
>   Absolute leader, remove fract*i*ons nearby (6)
>   Precious drink messed up *hear*ing aid (7)
>   Bl*i*nd *t*ige*r* t*a*lk; nai*ve* (9)
>   Dark t*im*es clo*t*hing sounds *o*f valiant st*r*uggle (10)
>   Yet mea*n*s etern*a*l, lose permanence (7)
>   Forcibly *p*rint m*a*il cont*r*ac*t* (11)

What did this cheerful puzzler say?

Comment: perhaps cryptic clues tag as well?

Comment: I suggest you use "a murder" instead of "precious drink".

Comment: Look at the checked answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They weren't so cheerful - they said:

> "I'm scared, send help"!

Clue explanations:

> Title: `DOUBLE TROUBLE*`
>  1. `IN(-ti<)MATE`
>  2. `STAR<+CHAMBER`
>  3. `A(-fraid)+ROUND`
>  4. `(EARD+RUM)*` [indirect anagram of DEAR+RUM: note that indirect anagrams are generally not allowed]
>  5. `SPEAK+EASY` ["blind tiger" is slang for a speakeasy]
>  6. `NIGHTDRESS` ("knight duress" homophone?)
>  7. `HOW+EVER(-lasting)`
>  8. `LETTER+PRESS`

Getting the message:

> The italicised letters spell: "It came nearer; I hear it rave; I'm torn apart".
>
>  The last line is the key: each of these answers is made up of two words, and can be torn apart into those separate words.  IN+MATE, STAR+CHAMBER, A+ROUND, EAR+DRUM, SPEAK+EASY, NIGHT+DRESS, HOW+EVER, LETTER+PRESS. The first letters of each of these, in order, spell **I'M SCARED SEND HELP**.

Answer (score 0):

Further explanation for the cryptic clues (Suggestions added):

0. True blueblood made disturbance twice (6, 7)

> **DOUBLE TROUBLE** ([def] disturbance twice; **TRUE BLUEBLOOD** scrambled)

1. Captured confidante without it returning (6)

   > **INMATE** ([def] Captured; **IN**TI**MATE** for *confidante* without IT backwards)
2. Capricious committee accommodation after rats return (4, 7)

   > **STAR CHAMBER** ( ? ; **RATS** backwards plus ? )
3. Absolute leader, remove fractions nearby (6)

   > **AROUND** ([def] nearby; **A**bsolute + **ROUND**)
4. Precious drink messed up hearing aid (7)

   > **EARDRUM** ([def] hearing aid = sonething that makes you hear; **DEAR RUM** scrambled)
   >  Suggestion: A murder messed up hearing aid? (7)
5. Blind tiger talk; naive (9)

   > **SPEAKEASY** ([def] underground bar; **SPEAK** = talk; **EASY** = naive)
   >  Suggestion: Blind tiger talk; very simple (9)
6. Dark times clothing sounds of valiant struggle (10)

   > **NIGHTDRESS** ([def] night dress; homophone of **KNIGHT** = valiant plus ? )
7. Yet means eternal, lose permanence (7)

   > **HOWEVER** ([def] yet = but = however; **HOW** for *means* (as a noun) plus **EVER**lasting)
8. Forcibly print mail contract (11)

   > **LETTERPRESS** ([def] contract; **LETTER** plus **PRESS**)